# How does Hibernate map columns?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pojo

I am making a REST api by Spring to retrieve data from database. However I would like to understand how exactly Hibernate maps columns to the POJO?

Column names in the database are like 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME'. In the POJO, I make property names as 'firstName' and 'lastName'. However, Hibernate can still map correctly. How does that happen?

Comment: To avoid issues related to wrong mapping between columns and properties I suggest you to use the annotation @Column(name = "XXX") on the related field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally , we would use `@Column` to explicitly define the column name that is mapped to the a property. If no `@Column` is used , it will then use the configured naming strategies to determine which column should a property mapped to.

I am guessing you are using a customised [`PhysicalNamingStrategy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#PhysicalNamingStrategy) which map a  lowerCamelCase property to the HIGHER_UNDERSCORE column.

You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naming) for more information about the naming strategy behaviour.

---

As you mention in the comment you are using spring, I believe you are using spring boot too which by default which configure the physical naming strategy to `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy)) :

> By default, Spring Boot configures the physical naming strategy with
>   SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy. This implementation provides the same
>   table structure as Hibernate 4: all dots are replaced by underscores
>   and camel casing is replaced by underscores as well. By default, all
>   table names are generated in lower case, but it is possible to
>   override that flag if your schema requires it.
>
> For example, a TelephoneNumber entity is mapped to the
>   telephone_number table.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The thing is I did not use `@Column` as well and it is still mapping correctly. I just wonder what mechanism it is basing on.

Comment: Because if no @Column is used , it will then use the  naming strategies that you configured to determine the column name which I already said it my answer .

Comment: As I'm newbie to Spring I did not really configure any naming strategy. May I know PhysicalNamingStrategy will be applied automatically and take care of the mapping for me?

Comment: Well , it is not spring stuff, it is a Hibernate stuff. And yes , I believe a default `PhysicalNamingStrategy` will be applied if you do not configure it

Comment: See my update . If you are using spring-boot , it will configure a `PhysicalNamingStrategy` to you which change the name from camel case to  underscores

Answer (score 0):

I believe somewhere you have created a hbm file(basically for XML based and not for annotation-based since you didn't provide the code) which is the file written in XML. This is the file that allows to map the columns with the POJO class.
we can define the following mapping file, which instructs Hibernate how to map the defined class or classes to the database tables. (This is generally for your understanding)

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.nearex.scheduler.dto">
    <class name="SchedulerJobMaster" table="scheduler_job_master">
        <id name="jmId" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="FIRST_NAME"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="LAST_NAME"/>
        </property>              

    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

You can go through this tutorial for better reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm